# XNA Shader Matrix Parameter Broken

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, hlsl

Im working with model instancing in XNA 4.0 and I sending my model instance transformation in a parallel stream. Im following [this](http://sciencefact.co.uk/2011/12/hardware-geometry-instancing-in-xna-4/) tutorial. However when I want a matrix as input to my shader I get what looks like a damaged matrix, because I get strange projection results.

Does anyone know the source to the problem and why I can't pass the matrix when others suggest so?

Problem:

```
struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;    
    float3 Normal : NORMAL0;
    float3 UV : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 Color : COLOR0;
    float3 Tangent : TANGENT0;
    float3 Binormal : BINORMAL0;
    float4x4 World : TEXCOORD3; //Problem 
};
```

Changing the vertex shader function to the following does not help either:

```
VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input, float4x4 World : TEXCOORD3)
{

}
```

This works if I build the matrix with the vectors alone, I dont know why. Im I losing data?

```
struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;    
    float3 Normal : NORMAL0;
    float3 UV : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 Color : COLOR0;
    float3 Tangent : TANGENT0;
    float3 Binormal : BINORMAL0;
    float4 World1 : TEXCOORD3;
    float4 World2 : TEXCOORD4;
    float4 World3 : TEXCOORD5;
    float4 World4 : TEXCOORD6;
};
```

Vertex format:

```
internal struct InstanceDataVertex   
{
        public Matrix World;

        public InstanceDataVertex(Matrix World)
        {
            this.World = World;
        }

        public readonly static VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration
        (
            new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 3),
            new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 4, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 4),
            new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 8, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 5),
            new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 12, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 6)
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input registers on the GPU are limited in size. The size of `TEXCOORDn` is `float4` (as listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509647(v=vs.85).aspx)). There are no `float4x4` inputs.

Splitting your matrix across several input registers and then reconstructing it should work fine. It's just a matter of making sure the right values in your C# `Matrix` end up in the right places in your HLSL `float4x4`. I suspect the mapping is trivial, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

here is code I use in my project

```
 public Instance(Instancer instancer, float scale, Vector3 translate, Vector3 information)
    {
        ID++;
        id = ID;
        this.Scale(scale); 
        this.Translate(translate);
        this.Update(); //update the model matrix modelMatrix=scale*rotate*translate ma!

        Instancer = instancer;

        modelMatrix.M12 = information.X; //additional info unique for each instance
        modelMatrix.M23 = information.Y;
        modelMatrix.M34 = information.Z;
        Instancer.instanceTransformMatrices.Add(this, ModelMatrix);
    }
```

Model Matrix for each instance

```
  protected static VertexDeclaration instanceVertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration
    (
        new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.BlendWeight, 0),
        new VertexElement(16, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.BlendWeight, 1),
        new VertexElement(32, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.BlendWeight, 2),
        new VertexElement(48, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.BlendWeight, 3)
    );
```

List of Matrices to vbo where modelVertexBuffer is a quad or any other geometry

```
instanceVertexBuffer = new DynamicVertexBuffer(BaseClass.Device, instanceVertexDeclaration, instanceTransformMatrices.Count, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
            instanceVertexBuffer.SetData(instanceTransformMatrices.Values.ToArray(), 0, instanceTransformMatrices.Count, SetDataOptions.Discard);
```

Draw Function

```
BaseClass.Device.SetVertexBuffers(
                       new VertexBufferBinding(modelVertexBuffer, 0, 0),
                       new VertexBufferBinding(instanceVertexBuffer, 0, 1)
                   );

BaseClass.Device.Indices = indexBuffer;
BaseClass.Device.DrawInstancedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0,modelVertexBuffer.VertexCount, 0,2,instanceTransformMatrices.Count);
```

Sample Vertex Shader

```
 VertexOut VS(VertexIn input, float4x4 instanceTransform : BLENDWEIGHT)
 {
    VertexOut Out = (VertexOut)0;

  float4x4 world = transpose(instanceTransform);
  input.Position.xyz = float3(world._41,world._42,world._43);
```